# Add a defined amount to a value each day in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, date, time, calculator

I've a problem:
I have a website which should display a number in a specific div.
Now I want the number to increase by a specific amount every day, I am only allowed to use JavaScript and it should return the final number.

For example:
Today the number (start) is 100. Tomorrow it should be 110, the next day 120,... so the function should add 10 to the number each day.
I thought of a kind of loop but this would only work when I reload the site and wait a day :P Is there another option?
Thanks!

Comment: without more info on what this number is for it's hard to make suggestions, but a couple ideas are to tie the number to the date and increment it over time that way.  One way to do that would be to set the number to 100, then check the date on script load and add 10 for each day past your start day.   Another option is to cache the number in a file or cache and set up a script to increment it each night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to calibrate this a bit, but this should get you going

```
var startDate = new Date('2-10-2016');
var today = new Date();
var diff = Math.floor((today - startDate)/(1000*60*60*24))
var answer = 100 + diff * 10
```

Comment: i think var answer = 100 + diff * 10

Answer (score 0):

If you know the number N that should be added each day, you can actually implement do, in pseudocode:

```
numberOfPassedDays = Today - initDay
resultToShow = N * numberOfPassedDays + numberAtInit
```

and calculate it every refresh of the page (in your example `N=10` )